# OpenOffice partial cell in-between value copy function?

Tags: openoffice, worksheet-function

I have a very long worksheet list with contact information of various companies and I need to create usernames for them, so I would use the middle part of their website URL for those. For example, in cell `B1` I have `www.yourdomain.com` and I want to copy the `yourdomain` part to cell `A1`.

Many websites may have a different top-level domain than .com, but all of them start with 'www.', in the case of 'www.yourdomain.something.com' I would only need the 'yourdomain' part, so from the first dot till the next dot.

Is there a function to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested in OpenOffice but the following should work and may tide you over until better answers are offered. Use the formula in `A1` as shown (copy down as necessary):

[image: SU490624 example]

The formula is a little convoluted, so I have shown a way to build it up piece by piece which may also be a help in explaining it.

[Assumes a maximum initial string length of about 50 characters.]